# Stop WP7 emulator from launching on debug of Windows version

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, emulation

Currently I have a solution with Windows and WP7 XNA projects in it.

Whenever I try to debug just the Windows project it thinks it needs the WP7 emulator and decides to launch it. I opened up the Configuration Manager and created a new configuration just for Windows debugging and unchecked the building and deploying of all my WP7 projects yet it still insists on having the WP7 emulator open.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour?

Comment: Please provide what Visual Studio version you have. Express Version? More than one version installed on your computer?

Comment: VS 2010 Pro, only have the one installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet it's very similar to [this issue with multiple ASP.NET Development Server instances loading up](http://blog.geocortex.com/2010/06/04/always-start-when-debugging-preventing-multiple-visual-studio-development-servers-from-starting/) no matter what project is being debugged. I can't check this right now to be sure, but I bet there might be a similar setting to this "Always start when debugging" option for the emulator.

So opening the Properties Window (View->Properties Window, not the View->Property Pages one) and then clicking on the project in Solution Explorer, then look for a similar setting to "Always start when debugging".

*Alternatively*, have you tried setting the target to a be Device instead of the emulator? That might also be a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

In Configuration Manager uncheck deploy next to windows phone project

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because It's set as the startup project:

[How to: Set Startup Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y.aspx)